# how do I access a specific field in a compound index using mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to query my database to get back results for my API. As of now, I have a compound index to perform string searching:

```
diseases_collection.create_index([('url', pymongo.TEXT), ('headline', pymongo.TEXT), ('main_text', pymongo.TEXT), ('reports', pymongo.TEXT), ('diseases', pymongo.TEXT), ('syndromes', pymongo.TEXT), 
('event_reports', pymongo.TEXT)])
```

However, I want a way to search for geographical locations in the reports field only, and not the other fields. How can I do this? Each document has the following structure (obviously different values):

```
{ 
url: “http://outbreaks.globalincidentmap.com/eventdetail.php?ID=8237”, 
date_of_publication: “2011-02-22 12:29:00”, 
headline: “AUSTRALIA :: Anthrax scare closes Penrith tax office”, 
main_text: “[PenrithStar.com.au]  AUSTRALIA :: Anthrax scare closes Penrith tax office
At about 11.40am, a worker discovered some white powder, believed to have been part of a mail delivery.", 
 reports: [
   {
    diseases: “Anthrax”,
    syndromes: [],
    event_date: “2011-02-22 11:40:00”,
    locations: [“Sydney”, “Penrith”],
    event_reports:[“hospitalised”],
   }
 ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A collection can have at most one text index. When you specify multiple fields to be text indexed, they all are merged into one index.

Therefore you cannot query this index by values of only some of the fields you have indexed.